# What does List.Add(List[index]) creates a new object or a reference?

Tags: c#, list, object, reference, mutation

Ok so I have a `List<string[][]> myList` for storing a complicated set of strings.
Every time a new branch is needed, I need to add all the elements of the list to itself.

So this is what I am doing right now

```
 for (int k = 0; k < (count); k++)
 {
     myList.Add(myList[k]);
 }
```

But when I modify one of the list elements by doing a `List[index].SetValue(value, index)`
all the list elements in the list at that index get changed!

Any idea why? I am guessing this is because the `myList.Add(myList[k])` is creating a reference, so basically, how do I create it as a new Object?

Comment: Depends on the type of myList.

Comment: Oops sorry myList is a simple `List<string[][]>`

Comment: Add a clone of the object instead of the reference to the list.

Comment: Ok I see there is a `MemberwiseClone()` function assosiated with `List`. It says it creates a Shallow copy.
And wikipedia defines shallowcopy as follows:
_One method of copying an object is the `shallow copy`. In the process of shallow copying A, B will copy all of A's field values.If the field value is a memory address it copies the memory address, and if the field value is a primitive type it copies the value of the primitive type._ **The disadvantage is if you modify the memory address that one of B's fields point to, you are also modifying what A's fields point to**

Comment: Well, I guess that just does what my method does. So any change will get propagated through... Is there some other cloning method that does a `deep copy?`

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing... Kindly suggest a better method if you know one.

```
for (int k = 0; k < (count); k++)
 {
     myList.Add((string[][])myList[k].Clone());
 }
```

Is there any other way to do this? Without having to iterate through every list member?

Comment: `Clone` does too shallow a copy for a 2D array.  You need to write your own clone method that creates a new array and copies the individual strings over to it.  Or clones each 1D array in the second dimension.  Or use a 1D array to start with.